# org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException

Tags: sonarqube

I've installed Sonarqube on my Docker container.

It was working very well up to a point, and I able to access it from the Web UI.

I'm a running it like this:

```
sonar.sh start
sonar-runner -e
```

However, out of the blue I am getting

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 4.4.27-moby amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /root/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /root/sonarqube-6.2/bin/linux-x86-64/./.sonar
ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.104s
Final Memory: 1M/31M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:93)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:47)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:38)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is37Compatible(ServerVersion.java:58)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:36)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390)
        ... 15 more
```

Sonarqube logs have the following 4 errors:

```
ce.log:2017.01.31 13:22:29 ERROR ce[][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to pop the queue of analysis reports
sonar.log:2017.01.31 18:13:00 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] failed to start
web.2017-01-30.log:2017.01.30 18:25:59 ERROR web[AVnwoF863qSCVt7PAAAA][o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/
web.log:2017.01.31 18:13:00 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I am really surprised by this, since I haven't changed anything. I only added a `jar` to `/extensions/plugins/` and then I deleted it.

What's the cause of this error?

Comment: What does your server log say?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the errors that I found in `~/sonarqube-6.2/logs`

Answer (score 0):

As reflected by your server log excerpts, the connection to your SonarQube server is refused because it is not online. Why? Because

> `failed to start`

and

> `startup failed due to previous errors`

Get your server up and running. *Then* you'll be able to perform analysis.

Comment: I started it with `sonar.sh restart` and the output is `Started SonarQube.` So it is running, right?

Comment: Is the UI up & responsive?

Comment: No. That's actually the problem. The UI from `localhost:9000` doesn't work.

Comment: If the UI is not responsive, then the server isn't up and running

Comment: So the server is run with `sonar.sh start`, right? I am running that command. and indeed it looks like the server doesn't start. I showed in the questions the error that appear in the logs.

Comment: At this point, you should go to the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube). Comments are inappropriate for extensive debugging